# Upload file using PHP to FTP and get url

Tags: php, forms, upload, ftp

I would like to create a PHP form that is going to run on a local machine(WAMP).

This form is going to upload a file to a web server and echo the url of the uploaded file.

My skills in php are low, I can understand a code but I have difficulties writing one.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest learning how. Even if someone feels like abit of charity and writes the code for you, any changes/maintenance you might have to do in the future will be an absolute nightmare if you don't know how it works, and you'll have to find _another_ programmer feeling kind enough to fix it for you then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is just an automation, this form is not going to be accessible online but just on the lan using WAMP, it doest need to be too advanced. I did some research but when i try to apply the code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start.  Have a look at these tutorials

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/very-simple-php-file-upload

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472551

http://www.sitepoint.com/file-uploads-with-php/

**UPDATE:**

If you want to use a local version and FTP the file to another remote location have a look here

http://nirvaat.com/blog/web-development/uploading-files-ftp-server-php-script/

Comment: Thank you for your help, but from what i understand these forms upload the files to the local server. And I would like to upload it  to a remote server and retrieve a url like www.xxx.com/file.pdf